# Using VirtualHosts to host multiple domains

Tags: apache, dns, web-hosting

I have searched far and wide for this answer, and can't find a working solution. So here goes,

I have 2 VirtualHosts set up on my server, with each serving a separate domain name. However, when I visit the first domain on the list, it then serves the DocumentRoot of the second domain. I even have them both listening on different ports. In my DNS under each domain I've got them leading to the IP of the server.

Here is my Apache .conf file:

```
ServerName 137.117.33.226

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName joshstroup.me
        ServerAlias www.joshstroup.me
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/joshstroup.me.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/joshstroup.me.key
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName respice.xyz
        ServerAlias www.respice.xyz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/respice
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have NameVirtualHost? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: NameVirtualHost was deprecated back in 2.2 I believe, it's not used by the config parser anymore and results in a warning when trying to run a config with it in it